# Work with async services (observers) in angular2

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular-observable

Angular2\ES6:
I'm trying to build a page (model) that contains a set of filters which should get their data from a service (async) - 1 call per filter.
The model contains 2 main class: **Report** and **ReportFilter**. **Report** can contain several **reportFilters** (filters : ReportFilter[] = [];) and every **reposrtFilter** is populated from a service.
I've tried doing it all async using observbles, but the final result is that the filters are still without data in them (the service is reliable and returns data), when constructing the main Report class instance (this should be the starting point).
Any support would be appreciated !
See my code:
This is the **report** class:

```
export class CadasterReport
{
    filters : CadasterReportFilter[] = [];
    filtersIDs : number[] = [];
    activeReportFilter : CadasterReportFilter = null;
    constructor(  private filterService : FilterService,  private id : number )
    {
        this.filtersIDs =  this.getFiltersByReport();
        this.populateFilters().forEach(observable => 
        {
            observable.subscribe(result => this.concatData(result));
        });

    } 

    addToFilters(id : number, filters : CadasterReportFilter[]) : Observable<any>
    {
         this.activeReportFilter = 
         new CadasterReportFilter(this.filterService, id);

         return this.activeReportFilter.InitData();
    }

    concatData( result : any)
    {
        this.activeReportFilter.parseData(result[0]);
        this.filters.concat(this.activeReportFilter);//Here I except to see
        //that the this.activeReportFilter is already populated with the 
        //filter's data - it isn't
    }
    getFiltersByReport() : number[]
    {
        let filtersNumbers : number [] = null;
        switch (this.id.toString())
        {
            case ("10"):
                filtersNumbers = [10,20,30];
                break;
            case ("20"):
                filtersNumbers = [20,30,10];
                break;
            default:
               filtersNumbers = [30,10,20];
               break;
        }
        return filtersNumbers;
    }

    populateFilters() : Observable<any>[]
    {
        var filterObservablesCollection : Observable<any>[] = [];

       this.filtersIDs.forEach(filterID => 
       {
            filterObservablesCollection.push(this.addToFilters(filterID, 
             this.filters));
        });
        return filterObservablesCollection;
    }
}
```

This is the reportFilter:

```
export class ReportFilter
{
    private filterValues : string[] = [];
    private selectedValue : string = null;
    get ID() : number
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    set ID(value : number)
    {
        this.id = value;
    }
    private name : string = null;
    get Name() : string
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    set Name(value : string)
    {
        this.name = value;
    }
    public constructor(private filterService : FilterService,  private id : number ){}

    public InitData() : Observable<any>
    {
        return this.initFilter();
    }
    private initFilter() : Observable<any>
    {
        this.filterService.FilterID = this.ID;
        return this.filterService.GetFilterValues();
    }

    public parseData(result : any)
    {
        this.name = result.Name;
        this.filterValues = result.values;
    }

}
```

And this is my initial call from the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  private reportID : number;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,   private filterService : FilterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(( params: ParamMap) => this.initReport(params));
  }

  initReport(params : ParamMap): any 
  {
    this.reportID = params['id'];
    var Report : Report = new Report(this.filterService, this.reportID); 
  }
}
```

Comment: are you calling those service in ngOnChange() ?

Comment: No, I'm calling them from the very basic ngOnInit in the component (I've added the relevant component code)

Comment: place that service in ngOnChange(), as your making an async call, before you back the result the page is already loaded so if you place it in ngOnChange it will automatically fill the detail when you get back the result.

Comment: @Abhishek Ekaanth - this is not the problem - see my remark in the concatData function in the Report class:
   
        this.filters.concat(this.activeReportFilter);//Here I except to see
        //that the this.activeReportFilter is already populated with the 
        //filter's data - it isn't

Answer (score 0):

It all went well except for the parseData function which received result as an array instead of object.
I fixed the code:
this.activeReportFilter.parseData(result); 
should be
this.activeReportFilter.parseData(result[0]);